# Solution for the linear equations with triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a set of linear equations

$$
\mathbf{U}x = r \\
\text{where}\,  \mathbf{U} \, \text{is a positive upper triangular matrix and} \, r \, \text{ is a vector with positive elements in descending order} 
$$

Is it possible to write $x$ as product of a positive diagonal matrix and a vector of adjacent difference ? i.e.  $x = diag(y) adj(r)$ ? where $y$ is a vector of positive elements and $adj$ is the adjacent difference operator.

NB: adjacent difference operator simply returns the a vector with difference between adjacent vector elements and last entry padded with 0.  For example if $r = [7,3,1]$, then $adj(r) = [3-7,1-3,0]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the mapping $r\mapsto adj(r)$ is clearly not injective, there cannot exist a single $y$ such that $$Ux=r\implies x=diag(y)adj(r)$$

What's more, whenever the bottom right element of $U$, $u_{nn}$ and the final element of $r$, $r_{n}$ are both zero, there exists **no** such $y$ for which $diag(y)adj(r)=x$, because the final element of $diag(y)adj(r)$ is $0$, while the final element of $x$ is equal to $x_n = \frac{r_n}{u_{nn}}$.

Comment: clearly $\mathbf{U}$ is not unique.  regarding the second comment, it is assumed that $\mathbf{U}$ is positive.  I forgot to mention that positive without zero.

Comment: @Shew $U$ being unique doesn't make any sense. And $U$ being positive or not has no effect on the validity of my argument. Did you even read my argument?

Comment: Ok. What I meant is as far as I can see, elements of U can not be zero (that is what I meant by positive). So the last case you mentioned ($u_{nn} = 0$) will not happen and the last element of adj(r) is always zero. so last element of x is 0.